# Import soapui tests to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, soapui

How do I take imported SoapUI project and tie it to my current Maven Eclipse project, and be able to see this SoapUI project when I am in the Java Perspective view?

I have a SoapUI project that I would like to import into my Eclipse Maven project.
I can import this SoapUI project to eclipse when I go to the soapUI Perspective view and do a 'Import Project.'  This works great.
I want to have my maven plugin to execute the projects/testCases/testSuites in my current soapUI project file.
It is probably simple, I am just not seeing how to make this final connection between the soapUI and eclipse projects to run all projects and get reports.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html)You are probably looking for maven-soapui-plugin - configure it in your pom.xml build - block:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>soap-integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${basedir}/target/path/to/your/soapUIprojectFile.xml</projectFile>
                <!-- move reports directly to surefire-reports-->
                <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
                <!--move soapui-logs into target dir-->
                <soapuiProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>soapui.logroot</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/soapui/logs/${soapui.testsuite.version}/</value>
                    </property>
                </soapuiProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.junit_version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
         ...
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Look for more info [here](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html)